# Revoke-token error in oauth2 Django Oauth2

Tags: python, django, github, oauth, postman

I have such a trouble

I can't do **revoke-token** command in `oauth2 django`

**convert-token** works good,and i don't understand why,they are quite similar

I call each command with *PostMan*,but second don't want to work.

**Trace**:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "URL query parameters are not allowed"
}
```

In addition,i am doing it with YouTube guide,step-by-step,but nothing help
I was trying to call it from windows cmd,trying to search for different solutions online but nobody has the same.

***settings.py***

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = ''#i will hide it for my sec

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'ba_app',
    'users',
    'bootstrap3',
    'oauth2_provider',
    'social_django',
    'rest_framework_social_oauth2',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'be_aware_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'social_django.context_processors.backends',
                'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'be_aware_project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'article')
MEDIA_URL = '//'
LOGIN_URL = '/login/'

BOOTSTRAP3 = {
 'include_jquery': True,
 }

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # Others auth providers (e.g. Google, OpenId, etc)

    # Facebook OAuth2
    'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',

    # django-rest-framework-social-oauth2
    'rest_framework_social_oauth2.backends.DjangoOAuth2',

    # Django
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

# Facebook configuration
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = ''#i will hide it for my sec
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = ''#i will hide it for my sec

# Define SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE to get extra permissions from Facebook.
# Email is not sent by default, to get it, you must request the email permission.
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email']
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS = {
    'fields': 'id, name, email'
}
```

**GitHub oauth2 rep:**

https://github.com/RealmTeam/django-rest-framework-social-oauth2

It is my first question on Stack-Overflow,some recommendations on the way to write questions are ***welcomed***!

Answer (score 1):

Your parameters should be in the request body and not in the URL. If you work via Postman, you need to go to the "body" tab, select "x-www-form-urlencoded" and then enter your parameters.